# How can I prevent two operations from interleaving with each other whilst still allowing concurrent execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have two methods, `foo()` and `bar()`. There will be multiple threads calling these methods, possibly at the same time. It is potentially troublesome if `foo()` and `bar()` are run concurrently, as the interleaving of their internal logic can leave the system in an an inconsistent state. However, it it is perfectly ok, and in fact desirable, for multiple threads to be able to call `foo()` at the same time, and for multiple threads to be able to call `bar()` at the same time. The final condition is that `foo()` is expected to return asap, whereas there is no hard time constraint on `bar()`.

I have been considering various ways in which it might be best to control this behaviour. Using `synchronized` in its simplest form doesn't work because this will block concurrent calls to each method. At first I thought `ReadWriteLock` might be a good fit, but this would only allow one of the methods to be called concurrently with itself. Another possibility I considered was queuing up requests for these methods on two separate queues and having a consumer which will concurrently execute every `foo()` in the queue, and then every `bar()` in the queue, but this seems like it would be difficult to tune so as to avoid unnecessary blocking of `foo()`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any chance to make your object, which contains `foo` and `bar` methods, immutable?

Comment: Probably wouldn't help - the internal logic in this case involves both a remote API call and database access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good solution would be to make a separate class that controlled access to each of the methods.  You would create a singleton of this class, and then use it to control when it is OK to proceed with entering either method.

This is the third iteration.  This one prevents starvation.

Usage could be external to the foo() call:

```
em.enterFoo(Thread.currentThread());
foo();
em.exitFoo();
```

but would probably be cleaner as calls at the entry and exit of foo() instead, if possible.

Code:

```
public static class EntryManager
{
    private int inFoo = 0;
    private int inBar = 0;
    private Queue<Thread> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    public synchronized void enterBar(Thread t) throws InterruptedException
    {
        // Place the Thread on the queue
        queue.add(t);

        while(queue.peek() != t)
        {
            // Wait until the passed Thread is at the head of the queue.
            this.wait();
        }

        while(inFoo > 0)
        {
            // Wait until there is no one in foo().
            this.wait();
        }
        // There is no one in foo.  So this thread can enter bar.
        // Remove the thread from the queue.
        queue.remove();         
        inBar++;    
        // Wakeup everyone.
        this.notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void enterFoo(Thread t) throws InterruptedException
    {
        // Place the thread on the queue
        queue.add(t);

        while(queue.peek() != t)
        {
            // Wait until the passed Thread is at the head of the queue.
            this.wait();
        }

        while(inBar > 0)
        {
            this.wait();
        }
        // There is no one in bar.  So this thread can enter foo.
        // Remove the thread from the queue.
        queue.remove(); 
        inFoo++;
        // Wakeup everyone.
        this.notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void exitBar()
    {
        inBar--;
        // Wakeup everyone.
        this.notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void exitFoo()
    {
        inFoo--;
        // Wakeup everyone.
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Clear and concise. But I think a wait operation for either foo or bar becoming available should be added.

Comment: It's a fair concept, but as written it would not prevent starvation - a steady stream of one operation would prevent threads attempting to perform the other operation from ever completing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a name for that problem, so I would write my own synchronization helper object to deal with it.  It sounds a *lot* like a reader/writer lock, except that where a reader/writer lock allows any number of readers at the same time, or exactly one writer, but not both; your lock would allow any number of foo() or any number of bar(), but not both.

The tricky part is going to be ensuring that the lock is fair.  No problem if there's no contention, but what if the lock is in "foo" mode, and there's a steady stream of threads that want to call foo(), and just one or two that want to call bar().  How do the bar() threads ever get to run?

Actually, it reminds me a lot of a traffic light at a busy highway intersection.  The traffic light can allow cars to flow on the east/west route, or on the north/south route, but not both.  You don't want the light to switch too often and just let one or two cars through per cycle because that would be inefficient.  But you also don't want the light to make drivers wait so long that they get angry.

I've got a feeling that the policy may have to be custom-tailored for your particular application.  I.e., it may depend on how often the two functions are called, whether they are called in bursts, etc.

I would start from the source code of a reader/writer lock, and try to hack it up until it worked for me.

Comment: That is what I will likely end up doing (rewriting ReadWriteLock), but I wanted to see if anyone did recognise it as a solved problem first.